# Why can't my service commmunicate with the other services in the overlay network of my Docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine, docker-network

I'm having trouble communicating with my schema-registry and kafka-rest services from the other containers in the overlay network within my swarm.

After provisioning my nodes and joining them to the swarm, I created an overlay network using this command:

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable kafka-net
```

I created each service using these commands:

https://gist.github.com/jhines2k7/4c9e8d4c2c6ac60a076072cc28fad998

The service is running properly. Here's the log output from the schema-registry service:

https://gist.github.com/jhines2k7/39d6c6bc3dea5d1065718e87d7e3710a

All services in the swarm are running properly:

https://gist.github.com/jhines2k7/dc2ca41ebbf09c9fdf08e6527b72418a

I'm able to communicate with other containers in the network:

https://gist.github.com/jhines2k7/c746008e9da79f8e69a668751acfa602

All commands were run on a DigitalOcean Droplet running Ubuntu 17.10
Docker version 17.12.0-ce
docker-machine version 0.14.0

Comment: Are you running swarm in subnet? If so add your subnet and run the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by providing the proper value for the SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS env variable. Before, my command to create the schema-registry service looked like this:

```
docker service create \
--network=kafka-net \
--name=schema-registry \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zk1:22181 \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://schema-registry:8081 \
--constraint "engine.labels.node.type==webtools" \
confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:4.0.0
```

Notice the value for the SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS environment variable. After changing the value from http://schema-registry:8081 to http://0.0.0.0:8081...

```
docker service create \
--network=kafka-net \
--name=schema-registry \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zk1:22181 \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081 \
--constraint "engine.labels.node.type==webtools" \
confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:4.0.0
```

My schema-registry service was able to communicate with the other services in the swarm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you basing this off a swarm or compose setup others know works?

Also maybe try [turning off VIP for all services](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#endpoint_mode) so there's not a NAT in the middle: add `--endpoint-mode: dnsrr` to each create command.

Comment: Bret, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. The problems I was facing with my schema-registry service not being able to communicate with the other containers in my network was because I didn't provide the proper value for the SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS env variable. Ultimately my problem was caused by improper configuration.

Comment: One more thing, Bret. To answer your first question, I was following the Docker Quick Start guide at https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/quickstart.html. The directions aren't specifically for running a cluster in a swarm, but they do work.